# Rails 5, Query Interface Is Not Working on new added columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hey i got a really weird problem.I cannot use any queries on newly added columns to the model.

Here is the thing, I got this model;

```
  create_table "abouts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_abouts_on_slug"
  end
```

and I have added an integer column called sort_index with this migration and migrated;

```
class AddSortIndexToAbout < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :abouts, :sort_index, :integer
  end
end
```

When I do `About.minimum(:sort_index)` it returns `nil`

When I try `About.where('sort_index > ?',0)`
it returns an empty relation (all of about objects sort_index is set and larger than 0 i'm sure of it).

When I do `puts About.all`

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<About id: 1, created_at: "2018-07-19 19:34:56", updated_at: "2018-07-19 19:34:56", sort_index: 1>, #<About id: 2, created_at: "2018-07-19 19:35:04", updated_at: "2018-07-19 19:35:04", sort_index: 2>]>
```

When I do `About.where("id > ?",0).first.sort_index`

it returns `1` (which is what it should return).

The column is in the table,it has its value but i cannot use it on any query interface methods(I tried another newly created integer column it does the same)

It returns the same results on rails console.

Here is my model

```
class About < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :article, as: :art, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :article, reject_if: :all_blank

  translates :slug
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :globalize
  globalize_accessors attributes: %i[slug]
  def title
    article.friendly_id
  end
end
```

I have also tried to do a complete purge the database and re-migrate it.
Cleared cache fields.

Nothing seems to work.

Meager's request

```
2.5.1 :004 > About.where('sort_index > ?',0).first
  About Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "abouts"."id", "abouts"."created_at", "abouts"."updated_at", "abouts"."sort_index", "abouts"."anana" FROM "abouts" WHERE (sort_index > 0) ORDER BY "abouts"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]

 => nil 

columns_hash

2.5.1 :005 > About.columns_hash
 => {"id"=>#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x0000000003ec6690 @name="id", @table_name="abouts", @sql_type_metadata=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SqlTypeMetadata:0x0000000003ec6bb8 @sql_type="bigint", @type=:integer, @limit=8, @precision=nil, @scale=nil>, @null=false, @default=nil, @default_function="nextval('abouts_id_seq'::regclass)", @collation=nil, @comment=nil, @max_identifier_length=63>, "created_at"=>#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x0000000003ec5a88 @name="created_at", @table_name="abouts", @sql_type_metadata=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SqlTypeMetadata:0x0000000003ec5c18 @sql_type="timestamp without time zone", @type=:datetime, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil>, @null=false, @default=nil, @default_function=nil, @collation=nil, @comment=nil, @max_identifier_length=63>, "updated_at"=>#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x0000000003ec5588 @name="updated_at", @table_name="abouts", @sql_type_metadata=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SqlTypeMetadata:0x0000000003ec57e0 @sql_type="timestamp without time zone", @type=:datetime, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil>, @null=false, @default=nil, @default_function=nil, @collation=nil, @comment=nil, @max_identifier_length=63>, "sort_index"=>#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x0000000003eb7618 @name="sort_index", @table_name="abouts", @sql_type_metadata=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SqlTypeMetadata:0x0000000003eb7780 @sql_type="integer", @type=:integer, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil>, @null=true, @default=nil, @default_function=nil, @collation=nil, @comment=nil, @max_identifier_length=63>, "anana"=>#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x0000000003eb6f38 @name="anana", @table_name="abouts", @sql_type_metadata=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SqlTypeMetadata:0x0000000003eb71b8 @sql_type="integer", @type=:integer, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil>, @null=true, @default=nil, @default_function=nil, @collation=nil, @comment=nil, @max_identifier_length=63>}
```

Comment: Have you restarted your server?

Comment: Yes i did a dozen times sir.

Comment: Can you post some code and output demonstrating that `About.where('sort_index > ?',0) ` actually returns an empty set? Your next statement seems to contradict this, when you say `About.where('sort_index > ?',0).first` returns a value.

Comment: It returns nil, I have added the full console text to the question.You can look from there.

Comment: what's `About.columns_hash` return?

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: Try About.minimum("sort_index")

Comment: Same , returns nil.

Comment: What is the output of `About.all.map(&:sort_index)`?

Comment: its  => [nil, nil]

Comment: So that explains the problem :) When you inserted the values, did you actualy save the model? It tells me that you aupdated the records but didn't save them? That's just my thought.

Comment: Yeah man you nailed it right after i noticed the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was basically that my sort_index was null by default and i was forgetting to save it after setting it.

So i fixed it with a little concern

```
module Sortable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    default_scope { order(sort_index: :asc) }
    after_initialize do |obj|
      if obj.sort_index.nil?
        obj.sort_index = obj.id
        obj.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for all of the suggestions guys,these thing was bugging me for 6 hours lol :)

Answer (score -2):

You need to restart your console or run `reload!` in your console.

Comment: This thing happens on the web server too.It's not about reloading the console.

Comment: is there a min method for active_record? i tried User.min(:id) and got method_missing error. Then tried minimum and worked

Comment: Nah i tried minimum too ,it's my typo in the question.